# Multiple columns or single textfield?

Tags: cakephp, database-design

My question is about a logical problem which might has some impact in the future:

I allready habe 3 models (rooms, discipline, serie) and a model called printout.
In printout I can select a header image and define a header text, but how do I define what of those three models to use.

I see two possibilities:

- an own column in printout, for every model (rooms, discipline, serie)
- a single textfield which I parse later manually.

are there disadavantages betweeen those two ways. what is suggested.

I know its more a logical than a dev problem, still I want to choose the better way in the early stage of the project.

cheers endo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to do this is to use `foreign_key` and `model` fields in your printouts table (more details throughout this page):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#associations-linking-models-together

'foreign_key' is the id of the "other" model, and 'model' is the name of the other model.

So your Printout belongsTo all 3 other models and in the associations, you specify the condition of 'Printout.model' => 'Room' (or whatever model).

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more information of your table structure, how are your models connected (which one is parent, which one is child, and what you want to do exactly), so I can provide you a better answer.

Anyway, you don't have to bind the models at first, you can do that within your controller logic like this:

```
$this->PrintOut->bindModel(array(
    'belongsTo' => array(
        'Room' => array(
            'className' => 'Room',
            'foreignKey' => 'room_id',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Alternatively, if Room belongs to printout:

```
$this->PrintOut->bindModel(array(
    'hasOne' => array(
        'Room' => array(
            'className' => 'Room',
            'foreignKey' => 'printout_id',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Your solution might be something else too, but I will need more information of what your Models do.

**EDIT**

Now I see that your question might be a bit different... you should check binding models with conditions.

Comment: This is not good practice and there is no reason to use bindModel for this type of association. Associations should be handled in the model unless there is a reason to do so otherwise.  And in this case, it's very simple association.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the question at first, but left it there as useful information. But why is binding on the fly a bad practice?

Comment: Doing model logic in the controller is not ideal, and it's not good practice to use bindModel for something that normal associations can handle when there apparently is no need for dynamic associations.

Comment: Yeah, but if you use the binding only in a specific action, I think it would be better if you bind it within the action rather than modifying all default queries in the other actions to prevent getting large amount of unwanted data. Anyway, I didn't understand the question well, therefore this is not the right answer, I agree on that. And if I am wrong about the previous stated situation, please point out, I'm willing to learn something new. :)

Comment: "rather than modifying all default queries" - I think this is the issue.  It sounds like you're using recursive set to something other than -1 default.  Ideally, you'll set it to -1 in your AppModel, then all "default queries" are on the model only.  Any additional models you want to include can/should be included via ContainableBehavior, not recursive.